# awkward duplication in 2d array php

Tags: php, arrays

I merged two arrays together that both contained a string(url) and int(score). the following is a sample of the outome. Whenever a string is duplicated, i need to remove that string and its corresponding int. For example, on the 4th line (www.thebeatles.com/ - 30) should be removed. The 5th and 6th lines should also be removed as they appear already with a different score.

```
http://www.thebeatles.com/ - 55
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles - 49
http://www.beatlesstory.com/ - 45
http://www.thebeatles.com/ - 30
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles - 28
http://www.beatlesstory.com/ - 26
http://www.beatlesagain.com/ - 24
http://www.thebeatlesrockband.com/ - 23
http://www.last.fm/music/The+Beatles - 22
http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/the-beatles/id136975 - 20
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6tV11acSRk - 18
http://blekko.com/ws/http://www.thebeatles.com/+/seo - 17
http://www.adriandenning.co.uk/beatles.html - 16
http://www.npr.org/artists/15229570/the-beatles - 15
http://mp3.com/artist/The%2BBeatles - 14
http://www.beatles.com/ - 13
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TU7JjJJZi1Q - 12
http://www.guardian.co.uk/music/thebeatles - 11
http://www.cirquedusoleil.com/en/shows/love/default.aspx - 9
http://www.recordingthebeatles.com/ - 7
http://www.beatlesbible.com/ - 5
```

I'm new to PHP and my best efforts to get array_unique() to work have failed. Really appreciate some help guys!

Comment: `$result = array(); foreach ($array as $val) { if (!isset($result[$val['url']])) { $result[$val['url']] = $val; } } print_r($result);`

Comment: Thanks dave, I tried your code I thought it was gonna work but I got an undefined variable error in foreach(). was I supposed to change something?

Comment: Well yes you will need to change `$array` to whatever the name of your array variable is, and also I'm assuming that you have an array of associative arrays that have a key named `url` (where the URL is stored). I could give you a guaranteed working solution if you show a `print_r()` of your actual array - but I shouldn't really just be *giving* you the answers on a plate, we do like it if people put a *little* effort in themselves... ;-). I use the URL as a key in the result array to make dupe detection easy, you may want to pass `$result` through `array_values()` to make it indexed again.

Comment: Also I note from your comment on @Starx's answer that your input array is named `$result`, so you will need to change the name of the output array, my code would just overwrite your input array with an empty array before the loop.

Comment: @user1487983 - if you show the code you're using to merge the arrays, I'm sure you'd get some useful comments on it.

Comment: Dave as much as you probably want to, I wont let you give me the working code...its not the way I roll :-)

I'm just confused by this 'foreach' loop. don't have those in c+.

The two (2d) arrays i merged together both had [url] & [score]. now they belong to one big array called $result. Should I have changed the $array to $result? no?

I did it anyway...still didn't work :/

Comment: heres my code to merge the two arrays


 $result = array_merge($blekko_Array, $bing_Array);

Comment: Dave that was the problem. I was overwriting the new array with an empty one! thanks so much for your help I'm delighted with that. This community is fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that merges two arrays and discards any duplications, hopes it helps:

```
        function merge_links($arr_l, $arr_r) {
            $new_links = array();
            $links = array_merge($arr_l, $arr_r); //the big list with every links


            foreach($links as $link) {
                $found = false; //did we found a duplicate?

                //check if we already have it
                foreach($new_links as $new_link) {
                    if($new_link['url'] == $link['url']) {
                        //duplicate
                        $found = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                //not found, so insert it
                if(!$found) {
                    $new_links[] = $link;
                }
            }

            return $new_links;
        }

        $arr1[0]['url'] = 'http://test.nl';
        $arr1[0]['score'] = 30;

        $arr1[1]['url'] = 'http://www.google.nl';
        $arr1[1]['score'] = 30;

        $arr2[0]['url'] = 'http://www.tres.nl';
        $arr2[0]['score'] = 30;

        $arr2[1]['url'] = 'http://test.nl';
        $arr2[1]['score'] = 30;

        print_r(merge_links($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make link as key of the array which contains link and score. Corresponding to key there will always be one value. But the one which is added in the last will be there in your final array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even technically, those strings are not unique. i.e. They are completely different.

> - http://www.thebeatles.com/ - 55
> - http://www.thebeatles.com/ - 30

So, array_unique() will not give you the required output. One way of solving this issue is by defining a separate array and storing the URI and the number separately. A manageable form would be this.

```
array(

    array("http://www.thebeatles.com", 55),
    array("http://www.thebeatles.com", 30)

);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It's a 2d array. To print the results like that the code is

>
>for($x=sizeof($result); $x>=0; $x--){
>
>echo $result[$x]['url']." - ".$result[$x]['score']."<br>";
>

I just thought there was some way to detect duplication in the string parts of the array, then remove everything including the associated number

Comment: @user1487983, There are other ways, you can detect unique links, using regex. Do you have the link and the number as separate parameters? or are you scraping of a HTML text?